# Logstash: Pipe data from an input to another

Tags: input, elasticsearch, exec, logstash

Please I need to use some fields which I get from the first exec command, in another exec command, and I want to process all that in the input level, because I should output the result in elasticsearch.

Another way to process that is to link logstash output to its input again, please any idea ?

Comment: There may be other ways to solve the problem if you describe what you're really trying to do with the data.  What do the exec's do, etc?

Comment: yes maybe, in fact, I'd like to make a curl call to a rest api,and then retrieve the id and try to make another curl call using it and output that result to elasticsearch @AlainCollins

Comment: Still pretty generic, so it's hard to find an exact fit.  While there is an http *input*, there is no http *filter* to call other services.  If the extra data was in elasticsearch, there is a filter to query that source to extend your documents.  You might drop into the ruby{} filter to connect to the other services.  Depend on the data, you might also be able to use the translate{} filter.